# didDiscover peripheral not called

Tags: swift3, core-bluetooth

I want to use the CBCentralManager in order to find the bluetooth low energy peripherals around me. The centralManager is getting initiated, it starts correctly and it is scanning. But the didDiscover function is never called. I read all the other posts to this and similar problem and am 99% sure that my problem has not the same cause. Still, I cannot find what I did wrong.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

@objc(SmallerBeaconServiceImpl)
class SmallerBeaconServiceImpl : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    private let centralManager : CBCentralManager

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn && isRunning {
            startScanningForPeripherals()
        }
        print("updated state: \(central.state)")
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral.name ?? "no name")
    }

    func startScanningForPeripherals() {
        if centralManager.state != CBManagerState.poweredOn {
            return
        }

        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        print("is scanning: \(centralManager.isScanning)")
    }


    private(set) var isRunning = false

    func startListening() {
        if isRunning {
            return
        }

        isRunning = true

        print("started.")
        startScanningForPeripherals()
    }

    func stopListening() {
        if !isRunning {
            return
        }
        isRunning = false

        centralManager.stopScan()
    }

    override init() {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager()
        super.init()

        print("initiated")
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't set the delegate of `centralManager`.

Comment: @Larme: I would definitely add that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: that definitely helped. thank you! i would love to mark this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optional func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)` is a `CBCentralManagerDelegate` method.

Your class `SmallerBeaconServiceImpl` is compliant with `CBCentralManagerDelegate`, but you didn't set your `centralManager` `delegate` (`CBCentralManagerDelegate`) property. That's why `centralManager(_central:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi)` is not called.

This can be fixed with:

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```